# Symfony custom normalizer "the injected serializer is not a normalizer"

Tags: php, symfony, object

How do I use the normalizer correctly?
I have following code:

```
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new TestNormalizer(new ObjectNormalizer());

    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);
```

My TestNormalizer:

```
class TestNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{

public function __construct(private ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
{
}

public function normalize($object, string $format = null, array $context = []): array
{

    $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);

    return $data;
}

public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
{
    return true;
}

}
```

I try to convert an Entity to a json array and get following error:

> Cannot normalize attribute "xy" because the injected
> serializer is not a normalizer.

If this works, the object should be processed later on

Answer (score 0):

When using symfony serializations, you can get this error

This error happens when you use an ObjectNormalizer Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer

instead of an Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface

To avoit this error Use

Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

Source :
http://fikri.fr/cannot-normalize-attribute-because-the-injected-serializer-is-not-a-normalizer/